# integrating Cakephp with Informix database

Tags: database, cakephp, informix

I have an application and I want to use a table of Informix in my cakephp application. Is it possible?

I just want the users table of informix, the others tables i'll use mysql. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: There's a PDO_Informix driver available for PHP; as long as you have the correct ODBC driver installed on the machine, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but it needs information about how you can access the data. Is it standardised like REST/SOAP or something? Or do you need hard database access?

In general in CakePHP you build a custom datasource for it: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html or you can work with behaviours which you attach to models.

There are some examples of this approach like this for REST:
http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/06/01/rest-datasource-plugin-for-cakephp/